# Корректно ли при написании испанских имён использовать слова: барон, сеньор, донна?

Tags: стилистика

Скажите, пожалуйста, необходимо ли в научных работах при написании испанских имён:

1. Указывать дворянский титул: в салоне баронессы Валентайн де Сент-Пойнт прошёл концерт;
2. Использовать форму вежливого упоминания женщины/мужчины (сеньор, сеньора, донна): театральная труппа сеньора Иглесиаса была приглашена в Мексику для участия в фестивале.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Дон - это имя человека. Дон Карлос. А сеньор - это имя родовое - фамилия. Сеньор Хуарес, сеньор Иглесиас. Я думаю корректно, так как испанские имена отличаются от русских, там нет склонения и форм отчества, так что не всегда понятно о чем речь. Иначе придется писать Иглесиасович и не баронесса Джозефин Клэр Валентайн ( даже если мы берем английское имя аристократки Josephine Clare Valentine, Baroness Valentine, а Валентайн - это не имя, а фамилия, родовое имя), а Джозефина Валентайнова (а как материнское имя Клэр в отчество превратить - это отдельный юмор - Клэровна? Клэрович?). Так что лучше сохранять стилистику и писать и испанской логикой, смысл в которой как видите есть весьма существенный. Хотя английскую баронессу можно называть на английский манер, сохраняя стилистику английского языка. Титулы, имхо, надо сохранять, если вы не хотите ввести читателя в заблуждение, потому что персона с титулом, это совсем не тоже самое, что человек без титула - выходец из простого народа. Это в России буржуазию временно убрали в тень, а в Европе большая разница в статусе людей. То есть эта информация важная, как например, указание высокой должности или ученой степени, и тд. Вы же не напишите "Путин" или "Володя" сказал. Вы напишите "президент РФ Владимир Путин". Потому что **аргументация - это не апелляция к имени в паспорте, не "как его звать", а "кто он?" - как его называют, НО апелляция к значению имени человека, кого представляет этот человек - какого чина, звания, рода-племени, учёной степени?**

Если, конечно, в вашу задачу и задачу вашей работы не входит какое-то особое отношение к именам.

Например, дон Кихот, почему он Кихот, потому что это имя он сам себе придумал. На самом деле его звали Алонсо Кехана(в оригинале приводится рассуждение, что фамилия могла быть иной Кехата или еще как, но вроде Кехана - верно...). Так вот, тут есть смысловая игра, то что Кихот назвался не дон Алонсо, а выдумал себе имя, производное фамилии, но не фамилию. Забавная деталь. Родовое имя в свою очередь указывает на принадлежность к роду кого-то - сеньора, либо именование сеньора: Иванов - сын Ивана, Шуйский - сын, внук, правнук Шуйского, того, кого *прозвали* Шуйским и тд. так вот, дон Кихот, отказывается как бы от своего рода, и создает новый род Кихотов, его потенциальные потомки носили бы фамилию Кихотович, а не Кеханович, хотя так как он бездетный дед, выживший из ума, всё это добавляет комичности истории. Ну и это история о безрезультативных попытках человека создать себе имя в новом, изменившимся мире.

*В старом мире человек мог обладать собственным Именем, а в современном мире обладает Статусом. Статус соотносится с аргументацией.*

Comment: Родовые имена (сеньор, сеньора) необходимо употреблять для того, чтобы не спутать имя с фамилией? А если, к примеру, приводится имя и фамилия человека (театр принадлежал сеньору Аполинарио Касересу)?

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов ладно, я похоже чепуху несу периодически или всегда. Не нужно в работе использовать, дон/сеньор используются при **официальном обращении** устно или в письме. Дон чаще к близким, а сеньор к не близким. Сеньор можно употреблять с именем и фамилией, дон только с именем. Это то что у нас пишут "уважаемый Иван Иванович..", а раньше обращались "товарищ". Звание и должность - генерал, президент, директор желательно написать, чтобы было понятно, о ком речь, титулы,  можно употреблять, когда первый раз представляешь персонажа, но зависит от того, как будет фигурировать персонаж.

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов То есть не нужно: театр принадлежал Аполинарио Касересу.  Или просто "театр  принадлежал Касересу, часто имена не называют, сразу по фамилии. И далее просто по фамилии Касарес то-сё. вот например, статья про Салазара, на английском: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/António_de_Oliveira_Salazar 

"Salazar entered public life as finance minister with the support of President Óscar Carmona". Салазар вступил бла бла в качестве министра .. президента Оскара Кармона. И есть еще сложные фамили, вроде Лопе де Вега, который Феликс, его сначала с "де", а потом  просто Лопе зовут.

Comment: https://www.redalyc.org/journal/5175/517569474071/html/#:~:text=El%20primero%20de%20los%20cap%C3%ADtulos%20(%C2%ABLope%20de%20Vega%20y%20los%20portugueses%3A%20depreciaci%C3%B3n%20y%20glorificaci%C3%B3n%20del%20rey%20don%20Juan%20II%C2%BB%2C%20pp.%2017%2D37)%20comenta%20la%20atenci%C3%B3n%20que%20presta%20Lope%20a%20los%20temas%20portugueses%20y%20en%20especial%20al%20personaje%20de%20Juan%20II

Comment: Или в той же статье вики, если дальше смотреть : детство. Lope de Vega Carpio родился блабла, а ниже просто пишут Лопе, без де. При том что зовут его Феликс. Де Вега Карпио - это скорее всего указание на "дом" или клан. Знать представляли кланы, в кланах несколько семей, Первая фамилия - это от отца, а "де" это скорее всего принадлежность к дому или клану. Ну или Вега - это имя старшего в роду, основателя рода. Ну и  President Óscar Carmona - "президент" нужно писать. А Оскара Кармона зовут António Óscar de Fragoso Carmona. Видимо опустили де Фрагосо. Хотя скорее это вольность того, кто писал

Comment: Да и если что) то последнего далее называют Кармона, а не Оскар, так что фамилия сокращается, но в какую сторону я не знаю). Но если целиком напишите, думаю не будет критично, если не слишком длинная фамилия.